(React Native): Task :app:generateAutolinkingNewArchitectureFiles FAILED
This is my first React Native project, so please bear with me :)
I have been having TONS of build issues with Gradle, not being able to run ./gradlew clean, but now that works correctly.
I'm on react-native: 0.76.5, and Gradle 8.7.  However, in Android/build.gradle I have mentions of classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2")
I've been upgrading, downgrading, cleaning, and building trying to get this to work.  The initial issue I was trying to fix was similar to this question, but none of those suggestions worked, so I minimized my seeings files and have been trying to debug that way.
My current build error:
>>>/.gradlew build

> Task :app:generateAutolinkingNewArchitectureFiles FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:generateAutolinkingNewArchitectureFiles' (type 'GenerateAutolinkingNewArchitecturesFileTask').
  - In plugin 'com.facebook.react' type 'com.facebook.react.tasks.GenerateAutolinkingNewArchitecturesFileTask' property 'autolinkInputFile' specifies file '/Users/kevinzita/projects/eReaderApp/android/build/generated/autolinking/autolinking.json' which doesn't exist.
    
    Reason: An input file was expected to be present but it doesn't exist.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Make sure the file exists before the task is called.
      2. Make sure that the task which produces the file is declared as an input.
    
    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/validation_problems.html#input_file_does_not_exist in the Gradle documentation.

I had a pretty basic working app, but when trying to add references to React Native's Document Picker it has been riddled with errors.  I'm not sure which Gradle version is best to use, I tried using Expo for a few hours - which seemed to overcomplicate things.
Any suggestions, extra information I can add, or input would be very much appreciated.
